# Is the bridge created in Princeps referred to in other Imager books?

Tags: l-e-modesitt, imager-portfolio

The [Imager series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Imager_Portfolio) is (so far at least) two trilogies, the first set centuries after the other. In *Princeps* there is a dramatic battle scene in which the battle is won by creating a large stone bridge. Later, one character tells another it will probably stand for centuries.

In the earlier-released books, which are set later, does the narrative ever show us this bridge or mention its creation?

Answer (score 2):

Now that there are more books, I can answer this question.

Turns out the build-stuff-to-wipe-out-the-other-army strategy gets used more than once. In Imager's Battalion and Antiagon Fire, the imagers are very busy building stuff. Sometimes it's a dramatic battle scene, other times it's "well we should repair this so the army can continue its journey." The first few chapters of Rex Regis are a veritable catalogue of road and bridge building in Variana. They also include musings on renaming the continent from Lydar to Solidar and a new name for the city.

If you go back to book 1, Imager, and read the descriptions of the town in which our hero lives, his trip to the Council chambers with the little historical detail that it used to belong to the Rex centuries ago, and how it got covered in white alabaster, along with the detailed lists of what roads go around what hills, and of course the description of the Collegium, you will see that while the particular bridge in Princeps doesn't perhaps get mentioned in the earlier books, a whole lot of other imager-built bridges and roads do.